# Missing left parenthesis error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

```
select * 
  from student3
 where marks > (select avg(marks) from table)
```

missing left parenthesis error occurs when I am running query in Oracle

Comment: `table` is a reserved keyword

Answer (score 1):

As Gurvinder (@GurV) firstly pointed out, `table` is a reserved keyword in Oracle.  You can proceed with your current query by escaping `table` in double quotes, i.e.

```
select * 
from student3
where marks > (select avg(marks) from "table")
```

But you might want to avoid using `table` to name your database tables.